# Converting to a larger integer type

Tags: c, integer

I know this isn't the best question to ask on StackOverflow, but I'm looking for the term that is used to describe when converting to a larger numeric type to handle overflow. A basic example would be:

```
# int is 32 here
int a = 2147000000;
int b = 10000000;
printf ("The sum of a and b is: %ld", (long)a+b);
```

What is the term for 'converting to a wider type', whether done explicitly or implicitly?

Comment: @4386427 so this would just be considered a "conversion"? Is the term "up-conversion" or "down-conversion" ever used? What's the difference between promotion and conversion then?

Comment: @4386427 ok, thank you.

Comment: (Integer) promotion is when smaller integer types are changed to `int` before used in some types of expressions, e.g. `a = b + c`

Comment: Here's [a pretty nice wiki on the subject](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) of implicit/explicit
 conversion/promotion/transformation and ranks etc.

Comment: This can be called “widening.” This is not an official term of the C standard but follows from normal English and the official term “width,” which is the number of bits used to represent an integer type (including any sign bit but excluding padding), per C 2018 6.2.6.2 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the term for 'converting to a wider type', whether done explicitly or implicitly?

I recommend *widening* - effectively just what OP uses in the question.

C spec uses *wide, wider, widest* to describe going from some type to one of greater rank and range as in `int` to `long long`.  (*narrow, ...* to go the other way).  This also applies to `float, double, long double`.

`int` and `long` may have the same width though so `(long)a+b` does not certainly prevent overflow.  Using `long long` or `intmax_t` is more *likely* to provided extended range.

```
// printf ("The sum of a and b is: %ld", (long)a+b);
printf ("The sum of a and b is: %jd", (intmax_t)a+b);
```

See also [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil)

Answer (score 1):

From the standard (draft N1570):

> 6.5.4 Cast operators .... Preceding an expression by a parenthesized type name **converts** the value of the
> expression to the named type. This construction is called a cast.

So the standard uses the term: convert

So using a cast you convert an `int` to a `long`

The standard also often uses "conversion", like conversion from `int` to `long`

Comment: Thanks, have you ever seen up/down- cast/conversion used anywhere or is that just usually implied by the context of the cast/conversion and there's no specific term for it?

Comment: Don't recall seeing terms like up-conversion/down-conversion so it's for sure not common. On the other hand I can't say that it's never used (as I haven't read everything written about C). However, you wont find it in the C standard - that I'm sure about.